# Date comparison javascript

Tags: javascript

Is string comparison on the next manner reliable? In other words, how does this comparison internally works?

```
var _date = new Date();
var _start_date = _date.getFullYear()+"-"+_date.getMonth()+"-"+_date.getDate()+"-"+_date.getHours+"-"+_date.getMinutes();

if( _start_date < "2011-1-11-23-59")
    alert('still before the 11th of january!');
```

The above works perfectly, but how is javascript comparison works this way? I know i can calculate based on EPOCH and or new Date(), but in my case that isn't possible.

Answer (score 1):

This seems better to me:

```
  if (new Date() < new Date("January 11, 2011 00:00:00"))
     alert('still before the 11th of january!');
```

See

http://jsfiddle.net/uM3Mv/1/

and

http://jsfiddle.net/uM3Mv/2/

Comment: Hogan, that's right indeed, but mind the hours and minutes. In the case above this indeed not clear. The hours and minutes are very important in my case. Fyi: i also have a condition based on _start_date < "date" && _end_date > "date"

Comment: I added them for you -- there is the format -- that is midnight, use 24 hour clock. (in the test I just did 14:00:00 was 2pm local time)

Comment: In that case you can use if (new Date() < new Date(2011, 0, 11, 23, 59, 0, 0))

Comment: @Hogan: I didn't see the updated post while posting the comment ;)

Comment: @Cybernate : Happens to me all the time.